# UK Tier 4 proof of funds

Tags: visas, uk, study

My total university fee is GBP 20,800. I have paid GBP 10,400. Thus, when I submit my financial status, do I have to show the proof for the balance of the fee and maintenance?

If I have provided the proof of funds while applying for the CAS, and since the university sent the proof of funds to UKVI to get the CAS #,  do I repeat it when I apply for the visa with UKVI?

Are unit trust shares acceptable as proof of funds? Or can I tell them that I will be transferring the amount upon getting the visa?

Comment: Its a really nice question! but you might get better answers at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com